# Colocar campos text inline bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap

```html
<label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" for="last-name">*</label>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">

    <label>
      <input type="number" id="" name="protocolos[]"  class="form-control col-md-3 col-xs-3" style="width:65px;display:inline"/>            </label>

    <label>
      <input type="hidden" id="" name="siglas[]" value="'.$sigla.'" style="width:65px;display:inline"/>
    <label>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Pode explicar um pouco melhor a necessidade? Não consegui entender...

Comment: Não tem sentido transformar o elemento em inline e setar width, porque o width não funciona em elementos inline. Talvez o que vc queira é inline-block.

Comment: Isadora o seu problema MUITO provavelmente é com a importação do Bootstrap na página! Eu testei aqui e ficou o * e o input na mesma linha sem problemas. Se quiser eu posto a resposta com o código

Comment: Oi, gente! Obrigada pelas respostas! @dvd vou testar o  inline-block. O width é apenas p diminuir o tamanho do campo.

Comment: @DiegoSantos apenas quero colocar campos do tipo text na mesma linha, queria saber se o bootstrap tem alguma classe especial p isso.

Comment: @hugocsl se você não se importa em compartilhar, ficaria agradecida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isadora de acordo com a Documentação do Bootstrap a forma de fazer o formulário "inline" é essa https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms-inline

O seu código tinha alguns errinho básicos como a tag `<label>` sem estar fechada e outro problemas de estrutura da organização do html.

Fiz esse modelo misturando o seu código e o da documentação do Bootstrap, acho que ele pode te atender da forma que vc deseja.

**OBS:** No primeiro exemplo o  <kbd>*</kbd>  está dentro da mesma `Col-` do `<input>` já no segundo exemplo o  <kbd>*</kbd>  está separado em uma `Col-` e o `<input>` em outra `Col-` *(mas tudo fica tipo inline)*

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                <label for="" class="control-label">*</label>
            <input type="number" id="" name="protocolos[]" class="form-control" style="width:65px;display:inline"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="" class="control-label col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">*</label>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
            <input type="text" id="" name="siglas[]" class="form-control" value="'.$sigla.'" style="width:65px;display:inline"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Qualquer dúvida é só falar